# Given a list of CIDR blocks, how to efficiently find which block an IP address belongs to in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ip-address

I have a list of 200k+ IP addresses (e.g. 198.161.1.1), and another list of 4k+ CIDR blocks (e.g. 198.161.0.0/16).

I need to try to match each IP in the input list to its associated CIDR block, if it exists.

I'm aware Ruby's `IPAddr` class can easily determine if a given IP is in a block like so:

```rb
require 'ipaddr'

ip = IPAddr.new('198.161.1.1')
block = IPAddr.new('198.161.0.0/16')
block.include?(ip)
```

However, doing a linear search of the list of CIDR blocks for 200k+ IP's takes a long time.

My first thought was to sort the data and attempt to do a binary search on the CIDR block list. However, I can't seem to find a way to get this to work with any standard libraries in Ruby. I found a gem called [Segment Tree](https://github.com/take-five/segment_tree) which at first seemed like a perfect fit for this task, but I found that it returned inaccurate results (would return `nil` for IP's which I know for a fact have a matching CIDR block).